# Prefill EditText according to buildtype

Tags: android, android-build-type

Is it possible to set text in `EditText` only for a certain buildtype?
I want the `EditText` in the app I'm developing to be prefilled when running the debug buildtype.
The only way I see this right now is by checking programmatically if the current the current buildtype is "debug" and call `setText()`.

I was hoping to be able to do this in a cleaner way. Perhaps something like the `tools` namespace in XML layouts.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I went with my own way of keeping it clean.
I've had a look at Aspect Oriented Programming and made an Aspect with AspectJ.

```
@Aspect
class PrefillAspect {

    @After("execution(* com.example.aspect.LoginActivity.onCreate(*))")
    fun prefillLoginForm(joinPoint: JoinPoint) {
        try {
            val activity = joinPoint.target as LoginActivity
            activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editEmail).setText("test@example.com")
            activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editPassword).setText("MySecretPassword")
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Log.e("PrefillAspect", "prefillLoginForm: failed")
        }
    }

}
```

I've added this aspect to my `src/debug/java` folder so this aspect is only applied when a debug build is run. There's no code whatsoever in my main source, so this will never be shipped and the code base remains clean.

I've written an article about this here: https://medium.com/@dumazy/prefill-forms-on-android-with-aspectj-97fe9b3b48ab

Answer (score 3):

You can put some text for different environment in your `build.gradel` file in `buildTypes`

```
//For Development Environment
buildConfigField "String", "text", "\"DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT TEXT\""

//For Live Environment leave it empty
buildConfigField "String", "text", "\"\""
```

Then in activity directly set it to your edittext without manually checking anything.

```
etValue.setText(BuildConfig.text);
```

**More preferred solution** (For direct XML)

instead of `buildConfigField` use `resValue` which will generate a `String Resource` for different environment when project get rebuilt.

```
//For Live Environment leave it empty
resValue "string", "text", YOUR_STRING_LIVE

//For Development Environment
resValue "string", "text", YOUR_STRING_DEVELOPMENT
```

and you can use it directly in xml as

```
android:text="@string/text"
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to avoid having these string files in my main source code. I eventually went with an AOP solution and posted my own answer here

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create debug and release folders under your src folder and there keep all the common resources with different values between debug and release version. So you will have:

> \src\release\res\values\strings.xml

with

```
  <string name="your_string">release_value_here</string>
```

and

> \src\debug\res\values\strings.xml

with

```
  <string name="your_string">debug_value_here</string>
```

and then in XML

`android:text="@string/your_string"`

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to avoid having these string files in my main source code. I eventually went with an AOP solution and posted my own answer here